# How to convert the datetime on server to local time?

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-clientobject

I am developing silverlight web part. So I am using the client object model.I am saving some data from my silverlight application to the sharepoint. The date data is stored properly. When I am trying to retrieve that data the date is changed completely. The date changes with difference in many hours. How to retrieve the correct date from sharepoint correctly using client object model ?

Comment: post some of your code so we can see how you are doing it! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of DateTime, use DateTimeOffset.  It will maintain the value in relation to GMT across all clients as well as the server.